java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MyApp"
Can anyone help please idk what`s wrong:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ShoppingActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginRegisterActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

package com.example.myapp

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApp : Application() {

}

and the error is like this:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.example.myapp.MyApp package com.example.myapp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~pZwZTuonxc3-s2MzsiIEYg==/com.example.myapp-b7-G1N5IL6IaJdxnNTBq6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~pZwZTuonxc3-s2MzsiIEYg==/com.example.myapp-b7-G1N5IL6IaJdxnNTBq6A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1466)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~pZwZTuonxc3-s2MzsiIEYg==/com.example.myapp-b7-G1N5IL6IaJdxnNTBq6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~pZwZTuonxc3-s2MzsiIEYg==/com.example.myapp-b7-G1N5IL6IaJdxnNTBq6A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(AppComponentFactory.java:76)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateApplication(CoreComponentFactory.java:51)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1282)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1458)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplicationInner(LoadedApk.java:1395) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6959) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2236) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/myapp/Hilt_MyApp;
        at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp.Hilt_MyApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~pZwZTuonxc3-s2MzsiIEYg==/com.example.myapp-b7-G1N5IL6IaJdxnNTBq6A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~pZwZTuonxc3-s2MzsiIEYg==/com.example.myapp-b7-G1N5IL6IaJdxnNTBq6A==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 19 more

This is the error I'm facing when I siwtch to kapt
Error: [Hilt] Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported metadata version. Check that your Kotlin version is >= 1.0 at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.metadataOf(KotlinMetadata.java:200) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadata.from(KotlinMetadata.java:182) at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1220) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataFactory.create(KotlinMetadataFactory.java:54) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.isObjectClass(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:102) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.kotlin.KotlinMetadataUtil.isObjectOrCompanionObjectClass(KotlinMetadataUtil.java:119) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.Processors.requiresModuleInstance(Processors.java:950) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.processModule(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:169) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.aggregateddeps.AggregatedDepsProcessor.processEach(AggregatedDepsProcessor.java:120) at dagger.hilt.processor.internal.BaseProcessor.process(BaseProcessor.java:195) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.process(incrementalProcessors.kt:90) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.process(annotationProcessing.kt:209) at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1023) at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:939) at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1267) at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1382) at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1234) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:92) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:33) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:47) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:320) at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:266) at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62) at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41) at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59) at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:170) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162) at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [Hilt]

at
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


[Hilt] Processing did not complete. See error above for details.

Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED

Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:149) at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:135) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:74) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52) at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:42) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:337) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:324) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:317) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:303) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:463) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:380) at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:116) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:138) at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:123) at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:35) at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:51) at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:54) at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.call(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:43) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:40) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$executeTasks$10(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:264) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:266) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$tryTransition$8(StateTransitionController.java:177) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.tryTransition(StateTransitionController.java:177) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.executeTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:255) at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.runWork(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:220) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109) at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.doRun(DefaultBuildController.java:181) at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.access$000(DefaultBuildController.java:50) at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController$BuildOpRunnable.run(DefaultBuildController.java:200) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.AbstractManagedExecutor$1.run(AbstractManagedExecutor.java:47) Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:283) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.lambda$waitForItemsAndGatherFailures$2(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:130) at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:321) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:304) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withoutLock(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:309) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:126) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:92) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:78) at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:66) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:256) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:233) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:216) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:199) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:166) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:105) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:56) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:56) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:67) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:37) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:28) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.executeDelegateBroadcastingChanges(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:100) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:72) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:50) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:40) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:29) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:179) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:70) at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175) at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:68) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:46) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:91) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:37) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:65) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:77) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:38) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:94) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:49) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:71) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:45) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNonEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:177) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:81) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:53) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:36) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:23) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:75) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupStaleOutputsStep.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsStep.java:41) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:32) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:293) at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspac


What does your gradle namespace look like

namespace = "com.example.myapp"

Does this answer your question? Hilt: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.kotlin20test.Hilt_MyApp"


First, make sure you have in app package build.gradle file the next line:

...
android {
    ...
    namespace = "com.example.myapp"
}
...


Verify if you included all necessary dependencies:


for root gradle file build.gradle

plugins {
  ...
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.44" apply false
}


for app gradle file build.gradle

plugins {
  id 'kotlin-kapt'
  id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}

android {
  ...
}

// Hilt requires at least JAVA 8 features.
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

dependencies {
  implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44")
  kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
  kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
}

// Allow references to generated code
kapt {
  correctErrorTypes = true
}


Make sure you using kapt as dependency and kapt as include, not annotationProcessor

...
dependencies {
    // Wrong!
    annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    annotationProcessor("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")

    // Correct!
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.2.0")
} 

UPD:
Check this stackoverflow. Seems like you have issues with the Kotlin version.

whenever i do kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44") instead of annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.44") i get an error Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'. and [HILT] so i saw somewhere to avoid i have to annotationProcessor instead and it worked so im stuck with the new error in logcat that i mentioned in my post

annotations that need to be processed on kotlin sources need to depend on processors via kapt. annotations that need to be processed on java sources can depend on processors via annotationProcessor or kapt. If you have a mix of java and kotlin sources that have annotations that need to be processed then you are forced to use kapt to handle both java and kotlin.

did you apply plugins { id 'kotlin-kapt' ... } for kapt? Can you show the error when you do kapt instead of annotationProcessor?

but why when i change to kapt i face an error that says as i told you task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'

because kapt is better. Could you include a full log when gradle task :app:kaptDebugKotlin fails?
I'm trying to help, if you want a successful result, you should cooperate, otherwise, I'll pass.

you can try ksp but it's up to you. https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-ksp

yes sir hold on a second ,im trying my best so this get fixed

just tested Hilt with ksp, works like a charm

so the problem could be in my gardle build or what do you think ?

check my answer i included the error

THANK YOU SO FKINNG MUUUCHCHCHC DUDE YOU ARE MY SAVIOR IVE BEEN STCUK IN THIS FOR LIKE 6 DAYS OMGGG I LOVE YOU

If you are using the new Jellyfish Android Studio, you might also consider updating your compileOptions at least to Java 19.
